# Remove system tray notifications

Tags: notifications, sharex

I'm so frustrated because there are options to turn off notifications in shares but sure enough every time I see the popups regardless of having turned notifications off in every way I know how.

Here's a video where you can see the problem because I cannot screenshot the notifications:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12_5zIVN-8zI__EntF096Rv_R6__8NQxS/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution.

[image: Image shows the ShareX Task Settings window (accessible walkthrough below):]

0. Be sure ShareX is up-to-date as of 10/8/2023 to be on my version (this may exist in earlier versions, but I didn't check).
1. Right-click ShareX in the tray.
2. Click Task Settings.
3. Under General click Notifications (second option in the vertical multi-select on the left).
4. Turn on "Show toast notification after task is complete". You can also see that I have "Disable notifications" and "Disable Notifications on Fullscreen" turned on, but I think that has to do with disabling other-app notifications during recording sessions.
5. In the Toast notification box, set Duration to 0.0 and Fade duration to 0.0. As an extra measure, I also made the placement top-left because I just don't want it in the way of what I'm doing on the bottom-right of the screen. Then I made my Left-click action Close notification for good measure.

Also, looks like "automatically hide on screen capture" would have allowed me to take a screenshot of the problem. Hopefully the text and video are sufficient.